# Pandas find duration between dates where a condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ VENDOR ID  ║ DATE        ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 33         ║ 01/12/2018  ║
║ 2 ║ 33         ║ 03/12/2018  ║
║ 3 ║ 12         ║ 01/08/2018  ║
║ 4 ║ 12         ║ 01/15/2018  ║
║ 5 ║ 12         ║ 01/23/2018  ║
║ 6 ║ 33         ║ 05/12/2018  ║
║ 7 ║ 89         ║ 01/12/2018  ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

And I'm hoping to get a table that gives me the number of days since the same VENDOR ID last occured, like so:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ VENDOR ID  ║     GAP     ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 33         ║ ----------  ║
║ 2 ║ 33         ║     60      ║
║ 3 ║ 12         ║ ----------  ║
║ 4 ║ 12         ║      7      ║
║ 5 ║ 12         ║      8      ║
║ 6 ║ 33         ║     60      ║
║ 7 ║ 89         ║ ----------  ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I've been trying to find a way to achieve this using groupbys and other tricks but can't seem to get anything to work.

I did come up with what I think might work using 2 nested for loops or iterrrows in pandas but because of the size of my dataset using nested loops won't really work.

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get a bit different output:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['GAP'] = df.groupby('VENDOR ID')['DATE'].diff().dt.days
print (df)
   VENDOR ID       DATE   GAP
1         33 2018-01-12   NaN
2         33 2018-03-12  59.0
3         12 2018-01-08   NaN
4         12 2018-01-15   7.0
5         12 2018-01-23   8.0
6         33 2018-05-12  61.0
7         89 2018-01-12   NaN
```

**Explanation**:

1. Convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)
2. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html)
3. Last convert `timedeltas`s to [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html)

Comment: `pandas 0.23.1`

Comment: Does this require rows to be sorted by date? I know the example in my question is already sorted but you may want to add that to the answer. Great answer btw, super quick and helpful.

Comment: @doddy exactly, need sortimg dates.